# foundation wrong css in links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, zurb-foundation

i'm just starting with foundation and i've installed foundation in my RoR application by gem, so i choose the Orbit home template and install it manually.

the problem is the links on the footer won't appear like the orbit-home example (a simple white-blue link that get little dark on hover).
My footer show link in black font and on hover font turns white with a black background.

I not changed nothing in original Foundation CSS and i haven't put any other styles.

If you want to see here is the link: [45.55.21.229](http://45.55.21.229/) (this is a personal site that i use to try and learn thing, so maybe can change when you see it)

the foundation change something or i'm doing something wrong??

PS: the li items comes with the dot mark before (list-style-type: circle). foundation wont remove this?

this is the head of my application:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "minha torta" %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Comment: Hi Icaro, you should know by now that you really need to add code to your questions rather than just linking to an external site. Please do so in order to avoid having your questions closed as off-topic!

Comment: i know that, but the code i'm using is the default foundation files without changes, and they are very large to i post and all. But i can put the head of my application page maybe can be usefull, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently,you have used rails scaffolding command, which generates css

Remove `app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss` file from your project

Comment: Thank you!! this really work, i know this is a newbie question but i cant figure that scaffold default CSS conflict with foundation.

Comment: No worries, had the same problem and took me a lot of time to figure out what was wrong

Comment: and about the list foundation wont change the ist-style-type: circle to ist-style-type: none?

Comment: In your styles put `ul li { list-style-type: none; }`, and if doesn't work, use `body ul li { list-style-type: none; }`